# How can I install extentions in chromium without having a google account?

Tags: chromium

I'm using chromium instead of chrome because I don't have a google account and don't want one. Is there a way to get these extensions without a google account?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome will work without a google account even extension can be installed without an account. The only functionality you should loose is to have it auto install the extensions to your other devices.

Tested with Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I'd prefer not to use chrome at all. But right now, I'm unable to install ublock origin without a google account. Even from ublock's main website

Comment: You could also try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480912/how-to-download-a-chrome-extension-without-installing-it or https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-install-chrome-extensions-manually/

Comment: This answer also applies to Chromium.  I installed LastPass to my portable installation of Chromium without a problem.